# Getting industry from Yahoo.Finance for list of stock ticker

Tags: r, web-services, finance, yahoo-finance, google-finance

How can I (preferably using R) get the industry classification for a list of stock tickers from Yahoo.Finance, Google Finance or anything else.
To illustrate, I have a list of tickers, such as

```
ticker_industy <- data.frame(ticker=ticker_list,industry=rep(NA,length(ticker_list)
head(ticker_industry)
    ticker industry
1      BDX       NA
2      BLL       NA
3       CB       NA
4     CELG       NA
5      CHK       NA
6       CI       NA
```

Preferably, R fetches the corresponding industry for each ticker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function should do the work for you...

```
industry=function(ticker)
{
  url=paste("https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q/in?s=",ticker,sep=',')
  mydata=as.data.frame(readLines(url))
  names(mydata)="text"
  ind=str_match(as.character(mydata$text[117]),'(?:<b>Industry: ?)(.*?)(?:<)')[,2]
  ind=str_replace_all(ind,'&amp;','&')
  return(ind)
}
```